What type of optimization can i use for entropy based minimization or maximization
So I have been struggling with a question for a while now. Say I have two signals (could be 1D or 2D). Let's call those signals, $S_1$ and $S_2$. I am trying to minimize the mutual information between them, such that:
$S_1 - C*S_2$
My goal is to get the best C value that will yield the lowest Mutual Information between these two signals. I can get this to work beautifully but it takes a very long time to iterate. What type of mathematical optimization tools can I use? I am specifically looking for ways to run this very fast.
